# Calling Instant Flow from SharePoint formatted column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to make a call to a Power Automate Instant Flow from a formatted column.  I'm taking my inspiration from this article - https://www.inspiribytes.com/power-automate/deploying-a-single-flow-to-multiple-sharepoint-libraries-lists/

I set up the column with the json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"0aa2105b-755e-4017-aac8-b1b823ea96d1\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Flow"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Start Approval"
    }
  ]
}
```

I created my Instant FLow, and noted the ID in the URL and changed the JSON in the formatted column to match.

When I click the button, I see a message that says "Setting Up" - clicking it, it just says "Waiting"

When I review the Developer Console, I see the following message:

POST https://prod-176.westus.logic.azure.com/workflows/b294beca8451414787bae052f8be6181/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=8s7N19sj-J3iZjMy90RvM7xKkcvujUkQCBPWxB6rZcc 400

So I'm getting a Bad Request, but I cannot figure out why.  There doesn't appear to be any other parameters that I should be setting other than the ID of the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I cannot reproduce your problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is no problem with your JSON code. I suggest you provide the screenshots of your flow, which will help us solve the problem better.